# Why is my spring boot stateless filter being called twice?

Tags: rest, spring-security, spring-boot, restful-authentication, jwt

I'm trying to implement stateless token-based authentication on a rest api I've developed using Spring Boot. The idea is that the client includes a JWT token with any request, and a filter extracts this from the request, and sets up the SecurityContext with a relevant Authentication object based on the contents of the token. The request is then routed as normal, and secured using @PreAuthorize on the mapped method.

My security config is as follows :

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private JWTTokenAuthenticationService authenticationService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .headers().addHeaderWriter(new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(XFrameOptionsMode.SAMEORIGIN))
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .and()
        .addFilterBefore(new StatelessAuthenticationFilter(authenticationService), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

With the stateless filter that extends GenericFilterBean defined as follows :

```java
public class StatelessAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StatelessAuthenticationFilter.class);

    private JWTTokenAuthenticationService authenticationservice;

    public StatelessAuthenticationFilter(JWTTokenAuthenticationService authenticationService)
    {
        this.authenticationservice = authenticationService;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(   ServletRequest request,
                            ServletResponse response,
                            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        Authentication authentication = authenticationservice.getAuthentication(httpRequest);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        logger.info("===== Security Context before request =====");
        logger.info("Request for: " + httpRequest.getRequestURI());
        logger.info(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
        logger.info("===========================================");

        chain.doFilter(request, response);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
        logger.info("===== Security Context after request =====");
        logger.info("Request for: " + httpRequest.getRequestURI());
         logger.info(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
        logger.info("===========================================");
    }

}
```

And the endpoint defined like this :

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user')")
@RequestMapping (   value="/api/attachments/{attachmentId}/{fileName:.+}",
                    method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getAttachedDocumentEndpoint(@PathVariable String attachmentId, @PathVariable String fileName)
{
    logger.info("GET called for /attachments/" + attachmentId + "/" + fileName);

    // do something to get the file, and return ResponseEntity<byte[]> object
}
```

When doing a GET on /api/attachments/someattachment/somefilename, including the token, I can see that the filter is being invoked twice, once apparently with the token, and once without. But the restcontroller mapped to the request is only called once.

```
[INFO] [06-04-2015 12:26:44,465] [JWTTokenAuthenticationService] getAuthentication - Getting authentication based on token supplied in HTTP Header
[INFO] [06-04-2015 12:26:44,473] [StatelessAuthenticationFilter] doFilter - ===== Security Context before request =====
[INFO] [06-04-2015 12:26:44,473] [StatelessAuthenticationFilter] doFilter - Request for: /api/attachments/1674b08b6bbd54a6efaff4a780001a9e/jpg.png
[INFO] [06-04-2015 12:26:44,474] [StatelessAuthenticationFilter] doFilter - Name:iser, Principal:user, isAuthenticated:true, grantedAuthorites:[user]
[INFO] [06-04-2015 12:26:44,474] [StatelessAuthenticationFilter] doFilter - ===========================================
[INFO] [06-04-2015 12:26:44,476] [AttachmentRESTController] getAttachedDocumentEndpoint - GET called for /api/attachments/1674b08b6bbd54a6efaff4a780001a9e/jpg.png
[INFO] [06-04-2015 12:26:44,477] [AttachmentDBController] getAttachment - getAttachment method called with attachmentId:1674b08b6bbd54a6efaff4a780001a9e , and fileName:jpg.png
[INFO] [06-04-2015 12:26:44,483] [StatelessAuthenticationFilter] doFilter - ===== Security Context after request =====
[INFO] [06-04-2015 12:26:44,484] [StatelessAuthenticationFilter] doFilter - Request for: /api/attachments/1674b08b6bbd54a6efaff4a780001a9e/jpg.png
[INFO] [06-04-2015 12:26:44,484] [StatelessAuthenticationFilter] doFilter - 
[INFO] [06-04-2015 12:26:44,484] [StatelessAuthenticationFilter] doFilter - ===========================================
[INFO] [06-04-2015 12:26:44,507] [JWTTokenAuthenticationService] getAuthentication - No token supplied in HTTP Header
[INFO] [06-04-2015 12:26:44,507] [StatelessAuthenticationFilter] doFilter - ===== Security Context before request =====
[INFO] [06-04-2015 12:26:44,507] [StatelessAuthenticationFilter] doFilter - Request for: /api/attachments/1674b08b6bbd54a6efaff4a780001a9e/jpg.png
[INFO] [06-04-2015 12:26:44,507] [StatelessAuthenticationFilter] doFilter - 
[INFO] [06-04-2015 12:26:44,508] [StatelessAuthenticationFilter] doFilter - ===========================================
[INFO] [06-04-2015 12:26:44,508] [StatelessAuthenticationFilter] doFilter - ===== Security Context after request =====
[INFO] [06-04-2015 12:26:44,508] [StatelessAuthenticationFilter] doFilter - Request for: /api/attachments/1674b08b6bbd54a6efaff4a780001a9e/jpg.png
[INFO] [06-04-2015 12:26:44,508] [StatelessAuthenticationFilter] doFilter - 
[INFO] [06-04-2015 12:26:44,508] [StatelessAuthenticationFilter] doFilter - ===========================================
```

What's going on here ?

### Edit :

It's even stranger than I first thought - implementing a simple endpoint that just returns a simple message displays the expected behaviour - it's seems like only when I try to return data as a ResponseEntity as above does this problem occur.

Endpoint :

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user')")
@RequestMapping("/api/userHelloWorld")
public String userHelloWorld()
{
    return "Hello Secure User World";
}
```

Output, showing single call to filter (with extra debug on):

```
[INFO] [06-04-2015 19:43:25,831] [JWTTokenAuthenticationService] getAuthentication - Getting authentication based on token supplied in HTTP Header
[INFO] [06-04-2015 19:43:25,844] [StatelessAuthenticationFilter] doFilterInternal - ===== Security Context before request =====
[INFO] [06-04-2015 19:43:25,844] [StatelessAuthenticationFilter] doFilterInternal - Request for: /api/userHelloWorld
[INFO] [06-04-2015 19:43:25,844] [StatelessAuthenticationFilter] doFilterInternal - Response = null 200
[INFO] [06-04-2015 19:43:25,844] [StatelessAuthenticationFilter] doFilterInternal - Name:user, Principal:user, isAuthenticated:true, grantedAuthorites:[user]
[INFO] [06-04-2015 19:43:25,845] [StatelessAuthenticationFilter] doFilterInternal - ===========================================
[DEBUG] [06-04-2015 19:43:25,845] [DispatcherServlet] doService - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/api/userHelloWorld]
[DEBUG] [06-04-2015 19:43:25,847] [AbstractHandlerMethodMapping] getHandlerInternal - Looking up handler method for path /api/userHelloWorld
[DEBUG] [06-04-2015 19:43:25,848] [AbstractHandlerMethodMapping] getHandlerInternal - Returning handler method [public java.lang.String RESTController.userHelloWorld()]
[DEBUG] [06-04-2015 19:43:25,849] [DispatcherServlet] doDispatch - Last-Modified value for [/api/userHelloWorld] is: -1
[DEBUG] [06-04-2015 19:43:25,851] [AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor] writeWithMessageConverters - Written [Hello Secure User World] as "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@3eaf6fe7]
[DEBUG] [06-04-2015 19:43:25,852] [DispatcherServlet] processDispatchResult - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
[DEBUG] [06-04-2015 19:43:25,852] [FrameworkServlet] processRequest - Successfully completed request
[INFO] [06-04-2015 19:43:25,852] [StatelessAuthenticationFilter] doFilterInternal - ===== Security Context after request =====
[INFO] [06-04-2015 19:43:25,853] [StatelessAuthenticationFilter] doFilterInternal - Request for: /api/userHelloWorld
[INFO] [06-04-2015 19:43:25,853] [StatelessAuthenticationFilter] doFilterInternal - Response = text/plain;charset=UTF-8 200
[INFO] [06-04-2015 19:43:25,853] [StatelessAuthenticationFilter] doFilterInternal - 
[INFO] [06-04-2015 19:43:25,853] [StatelessAuthenticationFilter] doFilterInternal - ===========================================
```

Comment: I have something similar. I use a Grails app and Spring Rest as a back end. And an Angular app as front end on another server. When doing a http.post from Angular, in Grails the doFilterInternal method in my OncePerRequestFilter is called twice. After reading [http://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_methods.htm](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_methods.htm) it made sense to me that the browser was first using the OPTIONS request to find out the methods supported by the server. And then the POST request was sent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay - so this is pretty ridiculous, but it seems like it's an issue with the way I was invoking the request (via the POSTMAN Chrome Extension)

Postman seems to fire in 2 requests, one with headers, one without. There's an open bug report describing this here : 
https://github.com/a85/POSTMan-Chrome-Extension/issues/615

The behaviour is not seen if the request is invoked using curl, or just straight from the browser.

Answer (score 12):

It is a part of filters that has still some black magic for me (*), but I know that this is a common problem, and Spring has a subclass of `GenericFilterBean` specially for dealing with it : just use `OncePerRequestFilter` as base class and your filter should be called only once.

(*) I've read it could be caused by the request being dispatched multiple times via the request dispatcher

Comment: Thanks for this Serge, but even changing the filter to be a subclass of     OncePerRequestFilter doesn't help - I still see the additional call to the filter.